# I can't use Dart and Henson on android studio 2.2.3v

Tags: android, android-library

When i use https://github.com/f2prateek/dart

i already added to gradle

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'
    compile 'com.f2prateek.dart:henson:2.0.1'
    provided 'com.f2prateek.dart:henson-processor:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart:2.0.1'
    provided 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart-processor:2.0.1'
}
```

but i can't find Dart and Henson class.

i want to use like this lib [dart& henson git](https://github.com/f2prateek/dart/tree/6f173dd5505d912f22fa14c3db246a596abccf2e)

how can i use it?
android studio version is 2.2.3(latest)

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem when i use  https://github.com/f2prateek/dart according to it's document :

my gradle version is 2.2.3 and i just add this to my module gradle file

```
compile 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart:2.0.1'
provided 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart-processor:2.0.1'
compile 'com.f2prateek.dart:henson:2.0.1'
provided 'com.f2prateek.dart:henson-processor:2.0.1'

Intent intent = Henson.with(this)
    .gotoExampleActivity()
    .extra1("defaultKeyExtra")
    .extra2(2)
    .extra3(new User())
    .build();
startActivity(intent);
```

Android Studio 2.2.3 tip me  can't resolve "Henson" whith red color. 
I solve it whith just click android studio "run app" button, because the Henson class will produce when running.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLUeg.png)

Comment: Sorry，  the Henson class will produce when compile our project.